# Need to Run Windows Security Dialog Box from Command Line

Tags: windows

You know, what you normally get when typing ctrl-alt-del or ctrl-alt-end. Except in this scenario I can't press those keys, but I want to launch that box. Specifically I want to be able to pull up the change password dialog from the command line.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extension of the answer given by Raymond Chen. I shows how to call the WindowsSecurity from a batch file. Note that it will only work properly when connected by a terminal session to Microsoft Terminal Server.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off

:: See https://gist.github.com/DavidRuhmann/5199433 and 
:: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
:: for details.

CScript //E:JScript //Nologo "%~0" %*
exit /b

@end

try
{
    var objShell = new ActiveXObject("shell.application");
    objShell.WindowsSecurity();
    WScript.Quit(0);
}
catch(e)
{
    WScript.Quit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You call the `Shell.WindowsSecurity` method. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) includes sample code.

Comment: This works fine when connected to a desktop session.  But it doesn't work when using a RemoteApp. I think it worked before but I am not really sure. Maybe some update broke this functionality. The method succeeds but nothing happens.

Comment: @clst It worked. The remote system displayed its security dialog. But you can't see it because you are local.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong this seemed to always fail silently when there is no full explorer shell (with taskbar). https://stackoverflow.com/a/33425283/920122  
I have now used the RDWeb change password funtionality for our customers: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10755.windows-server-2012-rds-enabling-the-rd-webaccess-expired-password-reset-option.aspx

Answer (score 0):

OSK.exe will bring up an on screen keyboard.  It should allow you to hit ctrl-alt-del

Answer (score -1):

[control.exe password.cpl](http://www.geekgirls.com/windowsxp_controlpanel.htm) - will launch the password Control Panel applet.